# A string from a list of variables

Tags: javascript, string

This code return 5 random numbers. I´m trying to place them, one after another, into a string  inside the variable “together”…
Can you help me?

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("numero1"),
    num2 = document.getElementById("numero2"),
    num3 = document.getElementById("numero3"),
    num4 = document.getElementById("numero4"),
    num5 = document.getElementById("numero5"),
    listNum = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5],
    resetear = document.getElementById("reset"),
    cont = 0,
    together ="";

resetear.addEventListener("click",newNumber);

function newNumber() {

    var renNum = setInterval( function() {
        listNum[cont].innerHTML = numAleat(0,9);
        together += listaNumeros[contador].value; // 1st try
        cont++;

        if (cont == 5) {
            clearInterval(renNum);
            cont = 0;
        }
    },1000);
};

function numAleat(limInf, limSup){
    return limInf + Math.floor( Math.random() * (limSup - limInf + 1) );
}
```

Comment: Hi Alfredo and welcome to SO. Can you post code to show us what you have already tried to place these 5 random numbers into a string?

Comment: Use `+=` to concatenate a String.

Comment: Hi Timusan an PHPglue, I've just added my first try ( is above in the code)... but It doesn't work because it return 5 times "undefined"

Comment: Finally I got it putting "listNum[cont].innerHTML = numAleat(0,9)" in a variable...Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to concatenate the elements of any array you can use:
listNum.join('');

Comment: yes, I did it, but what I get is 5 times                                                               
[object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: listNum.map(ele => JSON.stringify(ele)).join('')

Comment: As using `getElementById`, I would have used [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/innertHTML).

Comment: so you need the content rather element object. (y)

Comment: yes, I need the content of each "numAleat(0,9)" and place it inside "together" list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 var renNum = setInterval( function() {
    listNum[cont].innerHTML = numAleat(0,9);
    together += numAleat(0,9).toString();
    cont++;

    if (cont == 5) {
        clearInterval(renNum);
        cont = 0;
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Doing this I get two different random number, and what I want is having in "together" variable the number I got in: listNum[cont].innerHTML = numAleat(0,9);